# Wordpress Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE

Tags: wordpress

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE in /home/chilinbk/public_html/kunde/tkh/wp-config.php on line 100

Line 100 is the last one. But I cant figure it out!

Hope someone can help me.

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
 *
 * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
 * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information
 * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing
 * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
 *
 * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
 * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', '');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'if4tkr3z8umc1m9k94gja2agq8tyuc5adboxyccimlswfocnozsiekmpso2udgin');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'l5pf9yf02yqfztyxfwz8ustkskcu3h1fuozohxnibjhwdpchqa9x43gx7nrsvirn');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'sv1pejwz3p9uujbpojwukoceleeagrrrwxqgnwuv3aahricp8eelrxme3yicdafa');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'sxizz7mc0kmafx0plgqmyub5jetjqtsudnwxlegcxtza3nc3xv0nqo4aqap8imzl');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'z674t27gm67tvjtq1achhdwxz2rmnrs7dht3a8vsanxwt9wsviab4ku7jeadhnxw');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'pjob5np9us1ob4e3oqkmyevc82n6vhagpoz4e4ezrwc8as0osejirfkomkgbtjuf');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'c4h8ag0aalctr7rxhj15iqqknpwv7wivqdqmnybowwbylwynlf7bk6vmcjfmyt5n');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'jtid8ydl4wq6wxgnxlfgsm7icpghitdkrgtkp7dix7oicyfrkgvp9m0kwtloupmi');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * WordPress Localized Language, defaults to English.
 *
 * Change this to localize WordPress.  A corresponding MO file for the chosen
 * language must be installed to wp-content/languages. For example, install
 * de_DE.mo to wp-content/languages and set WPLANG to 'de_DE' to enable German
 * language support.
 */
define ('WPLANG', '');

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
$base = '/tkh/';
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'kunde.chiliweb.no' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/tkh/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
p');
```

Comment: what is `p');` in your last file? that's make syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

The last row ( `p');` ) looks like a fragment from a line present there before. Just delete the remainders or restore to a previous version and you are fine.